# angular using @output to sent data from child to parent component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have some data that I am passing from my child to parent component and I want it to check if its empty or it has some value inside automatically.

this is in my login.compunent.ts - child ts

```
@Output() update=new EventEmitter<string>();
userEmail = "a@b.com";
authUser(loginForm) {      
      this.update.emit(userEmail);
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

this is in my app.compunent.ts - parent ts

```
  emailData:string;

  onUpdate(userEmail:string){
    console.log("userEmail")
    if(userEmail !== ''){
      this.emailData = userEmail
      console.log(userEmail)
    }
  }
```

this is in my app.compunent.html - parernt html

```
{{emailData}}
<router-outlet (update)="onUpdate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you completely but if you want to pass data from your child to your parent "automatically" I believe you have to implement a two-way bindable property.

You do that like this

child.ts

```
export class SomeComponent  {
  ...
     @Input() something;
     // it's important to name it with the 'Change' suffix 
     @Output() somethingChange = new EventEmitter();
  ...
```

parent.html

```
<some-component [(something)] = "someFieldYouWantToTwoWayBindTo"></some-component>
```

now whenever you update `something` from your child the field `someFieldYouWantToTwoWayBindTo` will also be updated

Now if you want to check what's in `something` and only filter certain cases then implement a setter for `someFieldYouWantToTwoWayBindTo`

parent.ts

```
_someFieldYouWantToTwoWayBindTo
set someFieldYouWantToTwoWayBindTo(value) {
    if(value !== '')
      this._someFieldYouWantToTwoWayBindTo = value;

}
```